# Firebase dynamic link with page preview disable not working

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I would like to disable efr param to 1 in our dynamic link from firebase, in order to skip the preview page and get directly to the appstore. Thinking it will work.. but now the link is not copied to the app on install. What is your solution here in order to not show the preview page, go directly to the appstore, and keep the url within the clipboard on install?

IMO, UX wise, it's nicer to not have the preview page, even if I add metadata to it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While there's an option to disable the app preview page, it's in place to ensure Dynamic Link reliability in iOS. You can have it disabled, but it won't guarantee that the FDL will work as expected in iOS. This is explained in more detail [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/link-previews#app_preview_pages).

Comment: agreed, I did discover that.